# How to send argument into bash from python?

Tags: python, bash

```
import os  
os.system("echo \"Hello World\"") 
Hello World
0
```

Now i want to send an argument into echo in python.

```
name ="ok"
os.system("echo {name}")
```

The result is `{name}`,not i expects.
How to get `ok` as result?
How to send argument {name}'s value `ok` into bash from python?

Comment: Use string formatting, in Py3.6 you also use an `f-string`, e.g. `os.system(f"echo {name}")`, in earlier forms of Python `os.system("echo {name}".format(name=name))`

Comment: In general, string formatting is not safe. You won't usually notice the problem with `echo`, but consider `os.system(f"ls {name}")` if `name` is a file name with one or more spaces in it. `ls` will receives multiple arguments of partial file names, not the full file name as a single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *right* answer is to use

```
subprocess.check_call(["echo",name])
```

This avoids the need to construct a string, quote things to protect them from the shell, the signal-handling effects of `os.system()`, and the temptation to ignore the return status.